# Singleton in Dagger on a method

Tags: java, dagger-2

In the Dagger documentation it shows this:

```
@Provides @Singleton static Heater provideHeater() {
  return new ElectricHeater();
}
```

I'm use to seeing singletons on classes where only a single instance of the class exists. What is the point of using @Singleton on a method? Even without Dagger, you don't get a single instance of a method. There are never multiple instances of a method regardless whether a class instance is a singleton or not. The docs state:

> The graph will use a single instance of the value for all of its
>   clients.

What exactly does that mean? Does it mean that every time the method is called, it returns the exact same instance of ElectricHeater?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a component that is also marked with `@Singleton`, and give it this `@Module` for it to be able to provide a `Heater`:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = HeaterModule.class)
public interface SingletonComponent {
    Heater heater();
}
```

Then you create an instance of this component as per usual with Dagger, and invoke the `heater()` method, you'll always get the same instance

```
SingletonComponent component = DaggerSingletonComponent.create();
Heater heater1 = component.heater();
Heater heater2 = component.heater();
assertThat(heater1).isSameAs(heater2); // heater1 == heater2
```

However if it were unscoped, or if you are talking to a different component instance, you'll get a different instance.

```
SingletonComponent component1 = DaggerSingletonComponent.create();
SingletonComponent component2 = DaggerSingletonComponent.create(); // probably a bug that you have *two* of a "singleton", but i've seen it before nonetheless
Heater heater1 = component1.heater();
Heater heater2 = component2.heater();
assertThat(heater1).isNotSameAs(heater2); // heater1 != heater2
```